# Interpretation of the PVM $\mu$ whose Bhattacharyya coefficient equals the fidelity: $\|\sqrt P\sqrt Q\|_1={\rm B}(P,Q|\mu)$

Tags: measurement, fidelity

***(Bhattacharyya coefficient vs state fidelity)*** Given two vectors $u,v$ with nonnegative entries, their [Bhattacharyya coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhattacharyya_distance#Bhattacharyya_coefficient) is
$$\mathrm B(u,v)\equiv \sum_a \sqrt{u_a v_a}.$$
Given two positive semidefinite operators $P,Q$, we can define their *fidelity* as
$$\mathrm F(P,Q) \equiv \|\sqrt P \sqrt Q\|_1 \equiv \operatorname{Tr}|\sqrt P\sqrt Q|
= \max_U\langle U, \sqrt P \sqrt Q\rangle,,$$
where $\|\cdot\|_1$ is the trace norm, the maximisation in the last expression is over all unitaries $U$ (of suitable dimensions), and the "modulus" is defined as $|A|\equiv \sqrt{AA^\dagger}$.
From $P,Q$, given a measurement $\mu$, we can also consider the Bhattacharyya coefficient associated to the outcome probabilities:
$$\mathrm B(P,Q|\mu) \equiv \sum_a \sqrt{\langle\mu_a,P\rangle\langle\mu_a,Q\rangle}.$$
One can show that for any measurement $\mu$, we have $\mathrm F(P,Q)\le \mathrm B(P,Q|\mu)$.

***(Specific statement at issue)*** Now, as shown *e.g.* in [Watrous' book](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewatrous/TQI), theorem 3.24, there is also always a projective measurement $\mu$ such that $\mathrm F(P,Q)=\mathrm B(P,Q|\mu)$. More specifically, this is the projective measurement with components the eigenstates of the operator
$$R \equiv P^{-1/2}|\sqrt P\sqrt Q| P^{-1/2}.$$
A concise rundown of the presented argument is as follows:

1. Observe that $Q=RPR$.
2. If $R=\sum_k \lambda_k(R) u_k u_k^\dagger$ then $\langle u_k u_k^\dagger,Q\rangle=\lambda_k(R)^2 \langle u_k, P u_k\rangle$.
3. Thus $\sqrt{\langle u_k u_k^\dagger,P\rangle \langle u_k u_k^\dagger, Q\rangle} = \langle u_k u_k^\dagger, P\rangle \lambda_k(R)$.
4. Conclude that $\mathrm B(P,Q|\mu)=\langle R,P\rangle=\mathrm F(P,Q)$.

The above works under the assumption that $P$ is invertible. When this is not the case the argument oughts to be modified as clearly $R$ is not well-defined as stated. I will however focus on the cases where $P$ is invertible here.

***(The question)*** While the proof obviously works, my problem with it is that it's rather, well, magical. By which I mean that I have no idea what this operator $R$, or in particular its eigenvectors, represent physically. Is there any way to more directly relate $R$ to the physical properties of $P$ and $Q$, or the relations between them? Alternatively, is there any intuition as to why this particular structure for the operator $R$ should turn out to provide the correct measurement via its eigenvectors?
Even better would be a more direct proof method, which doesn't identify the measurement as the eigenvector of some mysterious operator, but does it directly from the properties of $\rho,\sigma$.